# Saving a Point type to postgres with activerecord-postgis-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, gis, postgis

I am trying to save a geographic point to a postgis enabled postgres table. The table looks like follows:

```
address:string
longlat: point
```

The rails application is using activerecord-postgis-adapter. When i try and do:

```
l = Location.new
l.longlat = 'POINT(28.72292 77.123434)'
l.address = "My Address"
l.save
```

Activerecord is throwing an error

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type point: "0020000001000010e6403774bc6a7ef9db405347ef9db22d0e

It seems like activerecord-postgis-adapter is internally converting the point type to string before saving which should not be the case. Any help on where i am going wrong is appreciated.

Comment: You are missing an apostrophe after 'POINT(28.72292 77.123434)

Comment: Edited and added the aporstophe in the sample code.

Answer (score 4):

the WKT format cannot be used to update a geometry directly, unless you would be using a sql statement.

The easiest way is to use `Rgeo` (might need to include the gem explicitly):

```
l = Location.new
# POINT(28.72292 77.123434)
l.longlat = RGeo::Cartesian.factory(:srid => 4326).point(28.72292, 77.123434)
l.address = "My Address"
l.save
```

Alternatively, if you receive the WKT format, and do not want to parse it, you could do something like

```
l = Location.new
l.longlat = RGeo::Cartesian.factory(:srid => 4326).parse_wkt('POINT(28.72292 77.123434)')
l.address = "My Address"
l.save
```

If you do not want to use `rgeo`, you can use your database directly:

```
l = Location.new
l.address = "My Address"
l.save

Location.connection.execute("update locations set longlat=St_GeomFromText('POINT(28.72292 77.123434)', 4326) where id=#{l.id}")
```

but this requires two queries.

Note: I assumed in both cases your `srid` is 4326 (wgs84), you should change this if you need another coordinate system.